# PHP file ouputs the javascript code itself and not running

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to create an Edit Modal. Provided that I have the html code for this, I write this javascript/jquery code:

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function() {

    <?php
    $q  =  $db->query("select * from tblUnit where unitStatus <> '2'");
      while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
                                echo " <script type'text/javascript'> alert('1');</script>";
                                $unitID         = $r['unitID'];
                                $unitStatus     = $r['unitStatus'];
                                $unitNumber     = $r['unitNumber'];
                                $floorNumber    = $r['floorCode'];
                                $unitType       = $r['unitType'];   
    $t = $db->query("select floorLevel, floor_buildingID from tblFloors where floorLevel = '$floorNumber'");
            while( $u = $t->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                $floorLevel     = $u['floorLevel'];
                                $floor_buildingID = $u['floor_buildingID'];
                              $w = $db->query("select unitTypeName from tblUnitType where unitTypeID = $unitType");     
                              while($x = $w->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                  $unitTypeName   = $x['unitTypeName'];
    ?>
            $("#editModal<?php echo $unitID; ?>").click(function(){
              $("#editUnitNumber").val("<?php echo $unitNumber;?>");              

              $("#editUnitType").val("<?php   echo $unitType; ?>").material_select('update');              
              $("#editFloorNumber").val("<?php  echo $floorNumber; ?>");


            });
<?php }}}?>   
});
```

The code above is used to write the data from the modal, but instead it output this:

`$("#editModal5").click(function(){ $("#editUnitNumber").val("12002"); $("#editUnitType").val("4").material_select('update'); $("#editFloorNumber").val("12"); }); });`

How do I solve that? What causes this?

Comment: A PHP loop and database call inside a JS function? How is this JS function called? I think you should rethink your design.

Comment: I don't see the closing `</scirpt>` tag and you have `<script>` inside the `<script>` tags for alert. It is most likely has to do with the html syntax issues.

Comment: You are nesting multiple script tags, inside a loop, inside a script tag...

Comment: uh it has to be another way to deal with this maybe referencing your id's with on another convention. This one is dangerous and pointless

Answer (score 0):

Use json to pass data from php to javascript, instead of echoing everything out in one place. It may seem an overkill but it's readable, and is more beneficial on the long run.

The code below is not tested, but it should give you a general idea on how to approach these things. I did not include the second and third queries within the first while loop. You can nest the results from those queries in the $unit array and access the relevant data via additional loops in javascript.

Also, ideally you wouldn't just echo out the decoded array right after the php, a better solution would be to call a function in the footer, that would generate a script tag with all data that is used by javascript. Another approach is to use AJAX and get a json response only when you need it, then you would feed that same json to the loop.

```
<?php
    $q  =  $db->query("select * from tblUnit where unitStatus <> '2'");
    $units = [];
    while($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 
        $unit = [
            'unitID' => $r['unitID'],
            'unitStatus' => $r['unitStatus'],
            'unitNumber'     => $r['unitNumber'],
            'floorNumber'    => $r['floorCode'],
            'unitType'       => $r['unitType'] 
        ];
        $units[] = $unit;
    }
    $units_json = json_encode($units);
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    var units = '<?php echo $units_json ?>';
    var units_array = JSON.parse(units);
    // do some validation here
    for (var i = 0; i < units_array.length; i++) {
        // do some validation here
        $("#editModal" + units_array[i].unitID).click(function(){
            $("#editUnitNumber").val(units_array[i].unitNumber);
            $("#editUnitType").val(units_array[i].unitType).material_select('update');              
            $("#editFloorNumber").val(units_array[i].floorNumber);
        });
    };
});
</script>
```